# What type of connection to get for a web server

Tags: vpn, connection, ethernet, web

I've been doing some research about this topic but I had no luck finding my answer.

Will a 2Mbps G.SHDSL connection do the work or should I go with a 5/10/20Mbps Metro Ethernet connection?
Or am I in a completely wrong direction?
When I look for prices for a 5Mbps Metro Ethernet I get prices around $1500.

Thanks for helping me out here

Comment: To get better results with your questions, I would specify more detail about what your webserver does, what sort of traffic you expect, etc. Currently the question seems to lack basic research as outlined in the FAQ.

Comment: You've provided no information on what kind of traffic your website has.  A dial-up is probably sufficient if you're serving a single small static file to a visitor a day.  A 20Mbps connection isn't sufficient if you're Twitter.

Comment: Well, it's more a facebook like social networking website. I know that hosting on a dedicated hosting is much cheaper but I really think that it'll grow fast and I don't want to be kicked out hence setting up my own datacenter. The web pages' average size are around 400 & 500 kb each. I only wanted to know if there was a web server specific connection because I read everywhere that the metro ethernet option is generally used for point-to-point connection for real-time conferences etc. I guess I have to go with a 100mbps at first.

Comment: I really can't see a reason why you would be kicked out of a datacenter for generating traffic. If they know how to bill their customers, they'll be glad to see high usage customers. Use a datacenter, it's what they're there for. By the time you get your own datacenter up with some redundancy and reserve generators, you'll have spent a lot more.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I guess you're right. I'll look into the hosting companies for what the costs will be.

Comment: Oh, and what are the risks of my scripts getting stolen on a vps? Because that is my greatest concern

Comment: If you go with a reputable provider, minimal. If you go with the cheapest one you can find, it's still pretty low.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you'll be hosting. But regardless of that, for a general purpose web server, 10/10 would be the bare minimum nowadays.

I think you're looking in the wrong place. You should be looking into renting a VPS or a rack at a datacenter, where you'd get at least 100/100 connections to the main lines. It'll likely be cheaper in the end as well.

Comment: +1 everything else would be completely uneconomic for 1(!) server.

Comment: I disagree with the general hand-waving assumption of 10/10. We've got some quite functional websites running just fine on 2/2. They certainly don't serve large numbers of traffic, but they do serve about 500 mobile devices for 8 hours a day, each and every day. It all depends on *what* you're serving.